# Accessing posted form value Jquery ajax fileUploader

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I have implemented JQuery FileUpload using the example [here](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/06/file-upload-with-spring-and-jquery-part_2793.html)

I want to pass extra parameter with JQuery fileupload so i used *formdata* field to pass the values. Plz refer the code-snippet.

```
$('#upload').fileupload({
        dataType : 'json',
        sequentialUploads : true,
        formData : {
            projectId : '222'
        },

        done : function(e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function(index, file) {
                console.log(file);
            });
        }
    });
```

I can see the "projectId" value posted but not able to access it.

Firebug shows shows following POST information:

```
-----------------------------2784773938064489741662764824
```

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="projectId" 222

----------------------------- 2784773938064489741662764824
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="account.png" Content-Type: image/png PNG

However, i can access the file but not the *projectId* through my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<ProjectAttachmentDto> upload( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,  @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId ) {
    // Do custom steps here
    // i.e. Save the file to a temporary location or database
    System.out.println("Writing file to disk...done");

    List<ProjectAttachmentDto> uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<ProjectAttachmentDto>();
    for (ProjectAttachmentDto projectAttachmentDto : uploadedFiles) {
        System.out.println(projectAttachmentDto.getProjectID());
    }
    ProjectAttachmentDto u = new ProjectAttachmentDto(1,
            file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getSize(),
            "http://localhost:8080/" + file.getOriginalFilename());

    uploadedFiles.add(u);
    return uploadedFiles;
}
```

I am getting Error as *NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed*

I want to access the projectId value in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in one of my projects :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<ProjectAttachmentDto> upload( @RequestParam("file")     
       MultipartFile file, @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> p_parametresAjax ) {

    // Récupération du projectId 
    String projectId = p_parametresAjax.get("projectId").get(0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting Error:415 Unsupported Media Type
after adding @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> p_parametresAjax .

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ProjectAttachmentDto upload(@RequestParam Integer projectId,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    System.out.println(projectId);
}
```

The issue got resolved through above code snippet. Seems like i had some issues related to spring and eclipse. There is not much of difference codewise,  i tried implementing in one of the other system, and i was able to fetch projectId parameter.